# recursive return type

Tags: c++, c, recursion, typedef, return-type

I just browsed through [Mark Probst's diploma thesis](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/schani/diplarb.ps) and stumpled over the following code:

```
typedef void* cont(void);

for (;;)
{
    cp = (cont*)(*cp)();
}
```

I'm pretty sure the cast should read `(cont)`, not `(cont*)`, because he explains:

> The function wishing to do a proper tail call returns *the address of the function* to be called

And `cont` is already a pointer-to-function type. So let's change that line to:

```
    cp = (cont)(*cp)();
```

Now I was wondering, how can we get rid of the cast? Can `cont` be defined so it returns a `cont`? How would the `typedef` for `cont` look like? Do we need a helper type to achieve this? Is it impossible?

Comment: So, does not either Charles or Arkku's answer let you know why your assumption was incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `typedef void* cont(void);` `cont` defines a function type returning a `void *`. I think you are confusing it with `typedef void (*cont)(void);` or `typedef void *(*cont)(void);`.

I don't believe that it's possible to eliminate the need for a cast in this scenario but I'm open to be convinced otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The type `cont` is a function returning a `void` pointer. Therefore `cont *` is a pointer to such a function, and the `*` cannot be removed from the cast.